# How to get rid of white space that appears below and above text inside a td tag

Tags: html, css, html-table

What I am attempting to accomplish is that the background changes when a user hovers over the td element. What the my current code is doing is shown in the picture below:

[image]

I am trying to get rid of the white space so that the gradient fills the entire td/cell.

The code below is for one row of my table.

```
    <tr>
        <td class="itemTrue">
            <h4>AMA<br>ROUND ALUMINUM MAST ARM SERIES</h4>
        </td>
        <td class="itemTrue">
            <h4>AVPL-SSA<br>4 INCH SQUARE STRAIGHT ALUMINUM SERIES</h4>
        </td>
        <td class="itemTrue">
            <h4>SMA<br>ROUND ALUMINUM MAST ARM SERIES</h4>
        </td>
        <td class="itemTrue">
            <h4>AVPL-SSS<br>4 INCH SQUARE STRAIGHT STEEL SERIES</h4>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

Here is the CSS code that affects these tags.

```
table {
  position: relative;
  top: 50px;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 8px 7px #234229;
  width: 1300px;
  cell-spacing: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

table, td, tr {
  border: 1px solid black;
  font-family: 'Roboto Slab', serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  border-spacing: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  line-height: 14px;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}

td {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

#armPoles > td {
  border-bottom: 5px double black;
  margin: 0px;
}

.itemTrue :hover {
  color: white;
  background: #e4e4e4;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #e4e4e4 0%, #295534 73%, #1d3923 88%, #000000 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#e4e4e4), color-stop(73%,#295534), color-stop(88%,#1d3923), color-stop(100%,#000000));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #e4e4e4 0%,#295534 73%,#1d3923 88%,#000000 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #e4e4e4 0%,#295534 73%,#1d3923 88%,#000000 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #e4e4e4 0%,#295534 73%,#1d3923 88%,#000000 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #e4e4e4 0%,#295534 73%,#1d3923 88%,#000000 100%);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#e4e4e4', endColorstr='#000000',GradientType=0 );
}

h4 {
  font-weight: normal;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your missing a tag for your H4, why not set that as well. Also not sure which tag is messing up you can set different colour backgrounds to help you debug and learn.

So, try adding 'padding:0' etc etc to your css.

Comment: Your answer made me realize that h4 can also have margins and I fixed the issue now. Thank you very much! =)

Comment: your welcome, often its another pair of eyes, glad you learned more too.

Answer (score 0):

If you're putting the gradient on your `<h4>`'s on hover, you will need to take off the default margin `h4 { margin: 0; }`, alternatively you could put the hover effect on the td itself: `td:hover { background: blue; }`

Answer (score 0):

I think you need just

```
td:hover {
  background: linear-gradient(...);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I forgot that h4 can have margins and setting those margins up fixed the issue.

Thank you very much to everyone that came to help! =)